# Grouping a Data Column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 48 samples of zinc concentration reading. I am trying to group the data as Normal, High and Low (0 -30 low, 31 - 80 normal and above 80 high) and proceed to plot a scatter plot with different pch for each group.

here is the first 5 entries

sample concentration
1       1          71.1
2       2         131.7
3       3          13.9
4       4          31.7
5       5           6.4

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

In general please try to include sample data in by using `dput(head(data))` and pasting the output into your question.

What you want is called **binning** (grouping is a very different operation in R terms).

The standard function here is `cut` :

```
numericVector <- runif(100, min = 1, max = 100 ) # sample vector

cut(numericVector, breaks = c(0,30,81,Inf),right = TRUE, include.lowest = FALSE, labels = c("0-30","31-80","80 or higher"))
```

Please check the [function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/cut) to adapt the parameters to your specific case.

Comment: thank you very much. Can you kindly assist me with the code to attach a legend to my graph. i am using ggplot

Comment: @Chukwubuikem I'd encourage you to post a new question for that.